Google Tag Manager serverside via GCP - The request failed because the instance could not start successfully - Where to find additional logs?
I have a CloudRun running tag manager server side.
When trying to access /g/collect (or any other url for that matter) i'm getting:
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
In google cloud console log viewer, i'm getting "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully". That's the only info i can get.
Any other place we may look for additional information related to the error?
We're only getting "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully".
It's set to be automatically started and the max_instance variable is set to 1.
We currently have 0 instances running.

It was due to invoicing problems.
When accessing the "invoicing" page there was a red warning.
Still, a more detailed error message than "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully" would have been nice.
There was a single information-level log stating "Billing disabled. Shutting down instance." at the beginning of the incident.
We later found out that the google project administrator email was not checked in months, we could find many emails regarding the billing issues, so props for that.
